# Multi-Select Field No Longer Working

Tags: custom-fields

I have a site I manage that uses a "Multi-Select" HTML field type.  I do not use the field so I cannot say exactly how recently but no more than the last month our field stopped being able to be edited or shown in search forms.

If I switch to checkboxes it works perfectly. If I switch back Multi-Select I get the same problem and when I save I get the error, "Please enter valid - Data and Input Field Type."

It is like it is trying to use the pre-CiviCRM 4.5 form element. I do not know how that could be.

I am running CiviCRM 5.28.2 in Drupal 7.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: it can sometimes help others help you if you can try replicating the problem on one of the demo sites eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org which may either make it clear that it is not a current problem, or that it is and needs a fix. it won't help though if this is an issue where something old has broken with newer updates but regressions need finding and fixing too

Comment: I could not recreate this. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I could not recreate this. The most simple solution was to make a new field and then import the old data into the new field.